# Is it possible to block diagonalise a complex matrix with some arbitrary matrix elements?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, mathematica

I have a matrix of this form

\begin{bmatrix}
       \ 0 & v_1 & we^{-ik}           \\[0.3em]
       \ v_1 & 0           & v_2 \\[0.3em]
       we^{ik}             & v_2 & 0
     \end{bmatrix}
where $v_1$, $v_2$, $w$ and $k$ are some parameters. Is it possible to block diagonalise this matrix without specifying the values of $v_1$, $v_2$, $w$ and $k$? I have seen some examples about diagonalising a complex matrix. It seems that I need to calculate the eigenvalues, but this matrix does not have simple analytic eigenvalues. These are the eigenvalues calculated using Mathematica:
[image]

It is also weird that there are some imaginary numbers in the eigenvalues as this matrix is clearly Hermitian.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I can only guess that Mathematica is giving you something with imaginary components because it is assuming that your parameters may be complex.

Comment: I think that you'd find it easier to see what's going on if you were to do the following: replace $v_1, v_2$ by $u,v$; then divide by $u^2+v^2+w^2$ and forget about it until the end. The characteristic polynomial of the new matrix is then $X^3-X-uvw\cos k$ and I guess Mathematica will give you more "understandable" expressions for the eigenvalues. It might even then find you some eigenvectors ..